# How to insert a separator in Monotouch Dialog between elements without using RootElement

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

On the monotuch dialog github page it shows sections seperated by a space on the monotouch dialog sample. When I try to do this with the latest Monotouch Dialog it says that section is being used as an element.

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong or the correct way to add a seperator to a monotouch dialog screen?

Comment: Can you show us what you're doing ? and what's / where's *says that section is being used as an element* comes from ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found the solution to this. The solution to Monotouch Dialog separating sections with a space is to provide an empty "" header and footer to a section. Not intuitive but it works. Thanks